# Adding items to ListView from a Class

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am having trouble adding an item to a listview from one of my classes. I am missing something that is obviously over my head. If someone could help me to understand what I am missing that would be great.

I don't know how much detail I need to provide. What I am trying to do is to basic so I know I have to be missing something. I have a class that I am trying to use to add an item to a listview I have on a form. There are no errors thrown, yet nothing gets added.

I have even tried using something as simple as frmGiveaways.lstAccounts.items.add("wtf") in the class, it doesn't throw any errors, the line is processed, yet no items appear in the list.

What are some things that would keep me from being able to do this?

Here is the class

```
    Imports Simple_IRC_Client.Delegates
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Handles minimal IRC server response messages.
''' </summary>

Public Class OutputMessages : Implements IDisposable

#Region " Private Members "
    Private ReadOnly ColorQuit As Color = Color.FromArgb(102, 54, 31)
    Private ReadOnly ColorPrivmsg As Color = Color.FromArgb(76, 76, 76)
    Private ReadOnly ColorTopic As Color = Color.FromArgb(176, 55, 176)
    Private ReadOnly ColorKick As Color = Color.FromArgb(199, 50, 50)
    Private ReadOnly ColorUserEvent As Color = Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128)
    Private WithEvents _ircConnection As InitiateConnection
    Private _mainView As MainView
    Private _window As RichTextBox
#End Region

#Region " Constructor "
    Public Sub New(ByVal mainView As MainView, ByVal ircConnection As InitiateConnection)
        _mainView = mainView
        _ircConnection = ircConnection
        _window = _mainView.rtbChannelView
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region " EventArghs "

    Private Sub ServerResponse(ByVal serverResponse As String) Handles _ircConnection.ServerResponseOutputEventArghs

        ' This setting has only been added for demonstration purposes of what raw data
        ' looks like.
        If _mainView.mnuMainMenuOptionsrawData.Checked Then
            OutputResponse(_window, serverResponse, Color.Black)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim parts() As String = serverResponse.Split(" "c)
        Dim address As String = parts(0)

        Select Case parts(1)
            Case "PRIVMSG" : Privmsg(address, serverResponse.Substring(indexOf(serverResponse, 3) + 1).Substring(1))
            Case "JOIN" : Join(address)
            Case "PART", "QUIT" : Quit(address)
            Case "ERROR" : Disconnected()
            Case "332" : TopicOnjoin(serverResponse.Substring(indexOf(serverResponse, 4) + 1).Substring(1))
        End Select
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region " Private"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Outputs a GUI message on me/user Privmsg.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="address">The source of the user's local host.</param>
    ''' <param name="message">The message text.</param>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' Displays an output message to the normalview window with correct format and colouring on Me, 
    ''' User Privmsg.
    ''' </remarks>
    Private Sub Privmsg(ByVal address As String, ByVal message As String)
        Dim outputFormat As String = String.Format("<{0}> {1}", Split(address), message)
        OutputResponse(_window, outputFormat, Color.Black)
        Select Case message
            Case "" : _ircConnection.SendMessage(String.Format("PRIVMSG " & ConnectionInformation.Channel & " :" & "{0}", Split(address)))
            Case frmGiveaways.keyword
                _ircConnection.SendMessage(String.Format("PRIVMSG " & ConnectionInformation.Channel & " :" & "recieved keyword", Split(address)))
                frmGiveaways.lstAccountsEntered.Items.Add(Split(address))
        End Select

    End Sub

    Private Sub Join(ByVal address As String)
        If Split(address) = ConnectionInformation.ChannelNick Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim outputFortmat As String = String.Format("{0} has joined the conversation.", Split(address))
        OutputResponse(_window, outputFortmat, ColorUserEvent)

        'Welcome message proof of concept
        '_ircConnection.SendMessage(String.Format("PRIVMSG " & ConnectionInformation.Channel & " :" & "Welcome, {0}", Split(address)))

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Outputs a GUI message on user Quitting.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="address">The source of the user's local host.</param>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' Displays an output message to the normalview window with correct format on user Quitting with Quit message.
    ''' </remarks>
    Private Sub Quit(ByVal address As String)
        Dim outputFortmat As String = String.Format("{0} has left the conversation.", Split(address))
        OutputResponse(_window, outputFortmat, ColorUserEvent)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Disconnected()
        Dim outputFortmat As String = "Disconnected!"
        OutputResponse(_window, outputFortmat, Color.Red)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TopicOnjoin(ByVal subject As String)
        OutputResponse(_window, String.Format("The chat's topic is: {0} ", subject), Color.Black)
        NewLine()
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region " Output Response "
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Displays the servers output response message.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="control">The control name.</param>
    ''' <param name="output">The server output.</param>
    ''' <param name="color">The control output line color</param>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' Responsible for displaying all server and user response messages.
    ''' </remarks>
    Public Sub OutputResponse(ByVal control As RichTextBox, ByVal output As String, ByVal color As Color)
        Dim outputFormat As String = String.Format("{0}", output)

        If control.InvokeRequired Then
            control.Invoke(New OutputEventHandler(AddressOf OutputResponse), control, output, color)
        Else
            Dim start = control.TextLength
            Dim length = outputFormat.Length

            With control
                .AppendText(outputFormat & Environment.NewLine)
                .ScrollToCaret()
                .Select(start, length)
                .SelectionColor = color
            End With
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub NewLine()
        If _window.InvokeRequired Then
            _window.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf NewLine))
        Else
            _window.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
        End If
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Functions "
    ''' <summary>
    ''' 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="s"></param>
    ''' <param name="instance"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Function indexOf(ByVal s As String, ByVal instance As Integer) As Integer
        Dim startAt As Integer = -1
        For x As Integer = 1 To instance
            startAt = s.IndexOf(" "c, startAt + 1)
        Next
        Return startAt
    End Function

    Private Function Split(ByVal name As String) As String
        Return name.Split("!"c)(0)
    End Function
#End Region

#Region " IDisposable "
    Public Sub dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose

    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

The part I am having a problem with is PrivMsg under the Region Private.

Comment: `help me to understand what I am missing` more easily done if we could see some code (edit your question - code does not format in comments)

Answer (score 2):

you could create a method on the form which receives a string to create a new LV item from the text passed:

```
Public Sub AddNewLVItem(txtName As String)
    Dim LVI as New ListViewItem
    LVI.Text = txtName

    LVI.Group = xxx     ' whatever other props there are

    lstaccounts.items.Add(LVI)
End Sub
```

or shorthand, if there are no subitems, groups etc

```
  lstaccounts.items.Add(New ListViewItem(txtName))
```

EDIT:

TYPICALLY, the form name is blank on MDI child forms only, I am not sure why that is the case here, but it obviously is.  Forms are classes and SHOULD be instanced for use.  They can use the old default instance method (`FormName.Show`) but that exists mainly for compatibility back to the VB4/5/6 days when forms were something apart from classes.  The old default instance also makes it easier for tinkerers (non programmers) who dont have a clue about OOP, to get something woking easily.

First, you will need a reference to `frmGiveAways` with app level `scope` so that other classes all reference the same object.  Add a module to your project (if there is not already one) and add:

```
Friend frmGive As frmGiveAways
```

(Or change the form name to something like `FormGiveAways` so the instance name and all the code referencing it can still use `frmGiveAways`).

Now, when you go to show the form in the menu:

```
If frmGive Is Nothing Then        ' check to see if it already exists
    frmGive = New frmGiveAways
    frmGive.Show                  ' could be a separate 'If' if needed
End if
```

Now there is **one** instance of `frmGiveAways` using the reference `frmGive` and as long as everyone uses that reference, things will work fine.  In the 'Sub AddEntry' it would pay to set a break and monitor the Me.Name value for a while to make sure all the calling code is properly refactored.

HTH

Comment: Ok, this is really strange.

In the form I added:

    `Public Sub AddEntry(account As String)
        lstAccountsEntered.Items.Add(account)
    End Sub`

and called it from the Class:

`frmGiveaways.AddEntry(Split(address))`

The sub is processed, the string is passed, but still nothing gets added. I can add a button on the same form with code:

    `Private Sub btnPick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPick.Click
        lstAccountsEntered.Items.Add("test")
    End Sub`

and it adds the item just fine...

Comment: the code above does not add a string to the LV, it adds a ListViewItem.  Karl told you that and I've told you that.  You should at least try it.

Comment: How's this?

`Public Sub AddEntry(account As String)
ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(account))
End Sub`

or this?

`Public Sub AddEntry(account As String)
Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(account)
ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
End Sub`

or this?

`Public Sub AddEntry(account As String)
Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
lvi.Text = account
ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
End Sub`

None work despite still being processed without error and passes the string. I can add the same string using a button on the form though.

Comment: how does this class get a reference to `frmGiveaways`?  is that a global variable or the from name? is the form explicitly instanced?

Comment: It's the form name and it's not instanced. It's just a regular old form right out of the box. I can set a break and see the string in the `account`. yet it doesn't get added to the listview. I thought maybe changing the listview's Modifiers property to public would work, but no.

Comment: @JoshLs  set a break in the `AddEntry` sub and see if the code gets there when called. since nothing gets added except from inside that form, it sounds like an instancing issue - your `frmGiveaways` variable doesnt reference what you think it does.  Then press the button (have it call `AddEntry` too).  When it breaks, in the immediate window type `? me.name` - thats the form reference

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Learning as I go here. I was a little confused by your `? me.name` though I did find this. http://s24.postimg.org/plwwjmkat/name.png
Something I did find, but not sure what it means is this. First image was called from the class. http://s24.postimg.org/qzojexjk5/test.png This second image was called from the form. http://s24.postimg.org/y5gahdsn9/test2.png Notice the difference?

Comment: @JoshLs The immediate window lets you execute code on the fly such as change variable values. `? me.name` (? is shorthand for PRINT) would print the formname, which is what you later detected thru intellisense. You DO have a form instancing issue. The SUB is not 'talking' to the same form as when you click the button. How does the app start via a MainForm and is frmGiveaways that main form or a form your code calls?  Are you using MDI (the default new child form results in an empty name)?  I'll edit the answer above in a bit for the fix.

Comment: The startup form is Mainform. It has a Panel that loads mainview. On mainview I have a MenuStrip that calls the frmGiveaway.

Comment: Seems obvious, since adding a listview item with just a string parameter is perfectly valid, the problem is probably in the way the form is instantiated and you're not referencing it.  One way around this is to pass a reference to the listview when you call the sub routine.

Comment: see edit for the form inatancing and feel free to at least upvote for all this work....

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote or I would because you have tried to help me. Give me some time to review your edit and see if I can make sense of this. Thanks!

Comment: Ok well I've decided to just start reading up some more on the subject until I have a better grasp of what I have gotten myself into here. It's obviously more vastly different from VB6 than I was expecting. Anyone have some good literature on the subject?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard coding the listview, try passing it into the sub as a parameter.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Privmsg(ByVal address As String, ByVal message As String, ByRef LV as ListView)
    Dim outputFormat As String = String.Format("<{0}> {1}", Split(address), message)
    OutputResponse(_window, outputFormat, Color.Black)
    Select Case message
        Case "" : _ircConnection.SendMessage(String.Format("PRIVMSG " & ConnectionInformation.Channel & " :" & "{0}", Split(address)))
        Case frmGiveaways.keyword
            _ircConnection.SendMessage(String.Format("PRIVMSG " & ConnectionInformation.Channel & " :" & "recieved keyword", Split(address)))
            LV.Items.Add(Split(address))
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean like this?

`Public Sub AddEntry(account As String) ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(account)) End Sub`  

Doesnt work despite still being processed without error and passes the string. I can add the same string using a button on the form though.

Comment: I meant passing the listview into the sub routine, not just the string.  I added a sample to my answer.

Comment: it becomes a parameter.  In the statement where you call the sub routine add the listview object as the last parameter.  The same way you're passing the 2 strings

Answer (score 0):

The basic syntax to add items to a `ListView` is this:

```
' Create list view items
Dim item1 As New ListViewItem("Item #1", 0)
Dim item2 As New ListViewItem("Item #2", 1)
Dim item3 As New ListViewItem("Item #3", 2)
```

Then you can add the list view items to the list view, either individually or as a group, like this:

Adding item one-by-one:

```
ListView1.Items.Add(item1)
ListView1.Items.Add(item2)
ListView1.Items.Add(item3)
```

Adding several items at once:

```
ListView1.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {item1, item2, item3})
```

---

Note: The `ListView1.Items.Add()` and `ListView1.Items.AddRange()` methods both need `ListViewItem` objects, not string values.

Comment: I get that. Inside the form something as simple as lstaccounts.items.add("test") works fine. I am having the problem when trying to do this from a class using something as simple as frmgiveaways.lstaccounts.items.add("test"). There is no error but it's like there is some kind of access restriction, the code is processed yet nothing happens.

Comment: Ok I posted the class.